# how to delete the duplicate values from Dictionary in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

> To delete the Duplicate values from Dictionary

```
Dim obj_ref
Set obj_ref = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
obj_ref.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
obj_ref.Add "one","JAVA"
obj_ref.Add "two",".NET"
obj_ref.Add "three","C"
obj_ref.Add "four","C++"
obj_ref.Add "five","JAVA"
obj_ref.Add "six","C"
obj_ref.Add "sev","C++"
```

Comment: You don't have duplicates.  You can't add duplicates to a dictionary.  -Edit: Oops, didn't realize you meant values.  Like @Bond said, just add as keys and catch the failures. (maybe on error resume next)

Comment: @Adam47 You can have duplicate _values_, just not duplicate _keys_, which begs the question... why not just create them as _keys_ and then they're guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: JAVA,C,C++ are duplicate values,right ?

Comment: My question is to delete the duplicate values only ?

Comment: Create another dictionary, swapping the values with the keys and the dupes will be deleted. =)

Comment: @Bond,I did not get,please explain it clearly

Comment: I'll post an answer so I can include a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys must be unique in a Dictionary. So if you're trying to create a set of unique values, assign them as keys to your dictionary. Essentially, in your scenario, just swap the key name and the value.

```
Dim d
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

If Not d.Exists("JAVA") Then d.Add "JAVA", "one"   ' Will get added
If Not d.Exists("NET")  Then d.Add "NET",  "two"   ' Will get added
If Not d.Exists("C")    Then d.Add "C",    "three" ' Will get added
If Not d.Exists("C++")  Then d.Add "C++",  "four"  ' Will get added
If Not d.Exists("JAVA") Then d.Add "JAVA", "five"  ' Will NOT get added.
If Not d.Exists("C")    Then d.Add "C",    "six"   ' Will NOT get added.
If Not d.Exists("C++")  Then d.Add "C++",  "sev"   ' Will NOT get added.
```

Now, you can test to see if the key already exists in the dictionary and only add it if it doesn't already exist. It's impossible to add `"JAVA"` (or any key) more than once.

Comment: Fine,Thanq,it looks like static only,is there any dynamically can arrange the values ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "dynamically arrange the values"?

Comment: what You did,that is you know how many are there,what I want is without knowing the values.

Comment: What is the source of your data? Are you reading from a file? Do you have an array? I used string literals in my example, as you did in your question, but you can replace the string literals with variables instead and make this more modular. Also, are the numbers (`"one"`, `"two"`, etc) important? Because, if not, you can just use an empty string here or reuse the key name as the value name.